# Raspbian - Custom SPI Bus similar to custom I2c Bus

Tags: raspbian, spi

I am currently using this line to put in a custom I2C Bus in my boot/config file:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=6,i2c_gpio_scl=0
```

However, I want to be able to set up a custom SPI bus in a similar manner, but I cannot find any good documentation on this process online anywhere. Is there a way for me to configure this in the same way that I configure the I2C Bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no support for SPI bit bang in the Raspberry Pi kernel.  There is certainly no support in the Raspberry Pi device tree settings.

I think there is bit bang SPI master support in the Linux kernel.  I have no idea if this is enabled or not in regular kernel builds.

Superficially I can't think of any obvious reason support for SPI as master could not be provided.  It seems to be no more difficult than the support already provided for I2C as master.